# Does Vesper want to live at the end?

Tags: james-bond, casino-royale

I just watched the remake of Casino Royale with Daniel Craig again, and I noticed something: in the moment before she dies, Vesper seems to panic and try and say "I want to live", making her death even more sad, tragic and horrifying.

I've watched it over and over and I'm pretty sure, but perhaps I'm imagining things. Do other people see this, or is there corroborating evidence, perhaps from a script or novelisation (I'm pretty sure this scene is not from Ian Fleming's book)?

Comment: When I watched it, I thought it was supposed to be an authentic representation of her natural reflexes, and that it's hard to drown yourself because your brain and body automatically fight back at some point.

Comment: @Walt Yes that makes sense. So you definitely saw her mouth "I want to live"  too?

Comment: No, I don't remember that part, sorry. :/ [But looking at it now, it seems she's just saying 'No' and then swallows some water.]

Comment: I didn't notice her saying that. I think she was trying to say something, but Bond can't hear what it is, which just makes it all the more tragic.